# How to change/set DateTimePicker value

Tags: vb.net, datetimepicker

I am trying to set / change the DateTimePicker value (using vb.net) but can't work out how to do it.

I have added the control to the page and I have tried using the following code but it doesn't work and I can't work out how to set the value during run-time.

```
DateTimePicker1.Value = Now.Day & "-" & Now.Month & "-" & Now.Year
```

The format of the control is set to Long and it looks like this when first loaded:

**Tuesday, February 26, 2013**

But I can't work out how to change it.

The error I get based on my code above is:

**Conversion from string "26-2-2013" to type 'Date' is not valid.**

Anyone got any ideas ?

Comment: Did you just try `DateTimePicker1.Value = Now`? :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I ended up getting it working by doing the following:

```
DateTimePicker1.Value = New Date(2013, 2, 26)
```

I was loading the value wrong.

Comment: how about the time? if let say i'm using the "hh:mm:ss" format?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code on Form Load Event to set the date time picker value to today:

```
DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat="dd-MM-yyyy"
DateTimePicker1.Value=Now()
```