# Write to Date Time Picker

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Today, I want to write day, month, and year to a datetimepicker in Visual Studio.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@geboortedag", dtp_geboortedatum.Value.Day)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@geboortemaand", dtp_geboortedatum.Value.Month)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@geboortejaar", dtp_geboortedatum.Value.Year)
```

These work. I save day, month and year separately to three rows in my database.

However, when I want to call these values, I can't even run the thing without getting the following:

```
BC30068 Visual Basic AND  VB.NET Expression is a value and therefore cannot be the target of an assignment.
```

Here's what I tried.

```
dtp_geboortedatum.Value.Day = row("geboortedag").ToString
dtp_geboortedatum.Value.Month = row("geboortemaand").ToString
dtp_geboortedatum.Value.Year = row("geboortejaar").ToString
```

All I want is to put the day, month and year I have in separate cells into the date time picker when I open a record.

PS I also tried like the help page for the error says to write to a variable first but that does nothing to help. Perhaps I did it wrong but, I can't get it to work.

Also, I've been linked to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15082664/how-to-change-set-datetimepicker-value) but this does not fix the issue. I keep getting errors that integers are strings and cannot be converted to integers, but they're integers! They're integers when they start, they're integers when they're saved into a row for integers that saves integers, they're integers when they come out. Why aren't they integers in the end when nothing special happens to them but being inputted, saved, and called?

Comment: Please have a read of [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and make the appropriate changes to your code. Also, make sure you are using [`Option Strict On`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) so that Visual Studio can point out some problems for you, and even suggest fixes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change/set DateTimePicker value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15082664/how-to-change-set-datetimepicker-value)

Comment: @AndrewMorton i'm afraid the article is beyond my level of comprehension. I've run into it before, given it a read, reread, rereread but i'm afraid i'm too new to get what that's about. I doubt i'd get it even if it was in my native dutch. sorry for that.

Comment: @GaiusVulcanusDuodecimus OK, then start by putting `Option Strict On' as the first line at the top of the code, before anything else. There will be some problems indicated. Try to understand what the problems are, especially data type mismatches, and correct them. Then see if the program goes wrong in a different way, which may lead you to where the actual problem is.

Comment: @AndrewMorton thank you. i did that and it gave me something new: Error BC30512 Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Object' to 'Integer'. i don't see where the conversions happen so i'll look into this next. everything should be integers, except perhaps dtp_geboortedatum.value ... but i still have to check that.

Comment: @GaiusVulcanusDuodecimus Not using AddWithValue would amount to `cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@geboortedag", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int, .Value = dtp_geboortedatum.Value.Day})` etc. in this case. (Assuming cmd is an SqlCommand and not an OleDbCommand.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author)*.

None of the material I provided in the question is relevant. Turns out I had to use `dt.clear()`. I'm going to be honest, I don't know how this is the thing that went wrong.

I fixed the rest with `cdate()` and `Option Strict On`.

Answer (score 0):

its a very long time since touched VB.NET, but I think what you need to do is pass a DateTime type to the date picker to set its value as below;

dtp_geboortedatum.Value = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day)

So you will need to pass your year, month and day as integers

Comment: thank you for your reply. i tried this but i get Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Integer' is not valid. which is odd because i have no nulls in any of those components on any row, nor do i convert anything. i only deal with integers.

Comment: Not sure whether you meant that the row object are definitely not null? Or do you need to check that you have data in it. You could test them for null first.
P.S. perhaps you are already doing this; but I strongly advise that you seek out some learning material which suits your style to work on in tandem. Good luck :)

Comment: thank you, and i try. but if you have recommendations on how to visual basic for beginners i'd appreciate it. also big fan of frankie boyle

Comment: @GaiusVulcanusDuodecimus sorry its long time since I've used VB so I don't want to confuse you with incorrect syntax. But I would suggest you separate out the fetching of the row values from the assignment to the datetimepicker;
So in psueocode;

set variable1 = row("geboortedag")
put breakpoint on it and look at the content of variable1

you can test the datetimepicker by just assigning an actual integer, eg;

dtp_geboortedatum.Value.Day = 1

Not sure I can suggest any books at the moment, but also consider which media is best for you (eg video?)

Comment: video works, there was a microsoft course i went through to get the theory behind the basics.

Answer (score 0):

Just substitute your row integer values for the literals I used.

```
Private Sub SetDate()
    Dim myDay As Integer = 27
    Dim myMonth As Integer = 4
    Dim myYear As Integer = 2018
    DateTimePicker1.Value = New DateTime(myYear, myMonth, myDay)
End Sub
```